# alignment or formatting issue with elements in the header of my web pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page is a bit hand-knitted I know, but there is one issue that I am struggling with. The header has a banner served by  adserv software, and there should be a search box beside it. The page is 960px wide, and these two elements 'add up' to 928px.  On most browsers it is OK, but on some - including IE 9.0.8 and Chrome 31.0 it is dropping the seach box down below the banner.

The page is http://www.wine-pages.com.  The code of my site is:

CSS

```
    body,html {
    margin:0;
     padding:0;
     background:#FFFFB7;
    font-family: verdana, arial, 'sans serif';
     font-size:12px
 }

#frame {
     width:960px;
     margin-right:auto;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-top:auto;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:left;
         }

 #contentcenter {
     width:67.6%;
     padding:0px;
     float:left;
    background:#FFFFB7;
    }

 #contentright {
     width:300px;
     padding:0px;
     float:right;
     text-align: left;
    }

 #contentheader {
     font-family:verdana, Tahoma, arial, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-size:10px; color: #FFFFFF;
     font-weight:bold;
    background:url(images/mastheadWIDE.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
```

The html for this section is:

```
    <div id="frame">

<!-- start leader board -->

<script type='text/javascript'><!--//<![CDATA[var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://www.wine-pages.com/adserv/www/delivery/ajs.php':'http://www.wine-pages.com/adserv/www/delivery/ajs.php');var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
   if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
   document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
   document.write ("?zoneid=5");
   document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
   if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
   document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset :        (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
   document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
   if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
   if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
   if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
   document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
//]]>--></script><noscript><a href='http://www.wine-pages.com/adserv/www/delivery /ck.php?n=abb5290a&amp;cb=5' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.wine-pages.com/adserv/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=5&amp;cb=5&amp;n=abb5290a' border='0' alt='' /></a></noscript>

<!-- end leader board-->
<!--start winesearcher button-->

<div style="padding:0px;vertical-align:middle;float:right;width:200px;height:82px;background-color:#52BA71;border:1px solid #52BA71;margin:0px 0 0px 0;padding:3px;border-radius:0px">
<!--<form name="searchform" method="GET" target="_blank" action="http://www.wine-searcher.com/wine-select.lml?referring_site=TCWP">-->
<FORM METHOD="GET" target="_blank" ACTION="http://www.wine-searcher.com/wine-   select.lml?referring_site=TCWP">
<input type="hidden" name="Xfromsearch" value="Y">
<input id="Xwinename" type="TEXT" name="Xwinename" value="" title="Search phrase" style="width:193px;padding-left:4px;color:#525252;font-size:12px;background:#FFFFFF;border:1px solid #000000;border-radius:4px;height:16px;position:relative;margin-bottom:4px" placeholder="Wine name">
<br />
<input id="Xvintage" type="TEXT" size="4" maxlength="4" name="Xvintage" value="" title="Vintage (use 'NV' for non-vintage). Leave blank to search all vintages." style="width:76px;padding-left:4px;color:#525252;font-size:12px;background:#fff;border:1px solid #000000;border-radius:4px;height:16px;position:relative;margin-bottom:4px" placeholder="Vintage" >
<input type="submit" value="Search" style="cursor:pointer;width:91px;height:22px;color:#fff;background:#008000;float:right;border:1px solid #000000;border-radius:4px" name="searchbutton" onclick="return button_click();">
<div align="center">Wine-Searcher<br />Find wines and prices</font></div>
</form>
</div>
<p style="clear:both">

<!--end winesearcher-->
<p></p>
```

If anyone can offer advice I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Looks fine in IE9 and IE8 to me

Comment: Why are you mixing external and inline CSS? You should remove the inline and put them in your external. Also, have you tried wrapping your banner code in a div so it's easier to handle? Otherwise I'm not seeing how you would control it.